# Entity framework & business transactions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, 3-tier

I have a question related to `n-tier` architecture using `Entity Framework` on data-access level in web backend.
Please, share your experience with me - how do you organize business transactions over entity framework ?

- First that i found is using of `Unit Of Work` pattern. That `UoW`
  object is some kind of aggregator of repositories that shares the same
  `DbContext` between them. But i'm not sure that this approach could be useful with huge business-logic.
- Second approach is having of `Entity framework transaction factory` that will encapsulate creation of new transaction on business layer like

  ```
   using (var transaction = transactionsFactory.Start())
   { 
      //business logic here
   }
  ```

And have injection scope one per http request.
Latter on data-level i will call

```
     using (var db = dbContextFactory.GetContext())
     {
        //data operations
        db.SaveChanges();
     }
```

To perform `DbContext` operations in the same transaction.
Disadvantage of that approach is need to allow `distrubuted transactions` in `MS SQL Server`.

What approaches did you use and what advantages and disadvantages did you have?

Comment: Does your question considering BusinessLogic or DataAccess organization?

Comment: @MaxKvt Both. What approaches exist to organize business logic transactions over EF.

Answer (score 0):

For instance we have mix with UoW, Repository, [QueryObject](https://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2008/08/02/query-objects-with-the-repository-pattern/)